# Using Multiple filters in VBA || excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am new to VBA and need some help desperately. I have an excel file which has two worksheets namely "URLs" and "keywords". I need a macro that can select the keywords one by one and apply them as filters to the "URLs" worksheet, in such a manner that in the end we have a list of all the URLs containing at least one of the keywords.

For instance if I apply the filter using the first keyword "recipe", I should get,

- "simplyrecipes.com"
- "simplerecipewizard.com"

After that when I apply the second keyword "net", I should have

- "simplyrecipes.com"
- "simplerecipewizard.com"
- "topix.net"
- "stockinvestingbasics.net"
- "techdailynews.net"
- "theanimeplace.net"
- "seniorhousingnet.com"
- "wordcounter.net" and so on.

You can download the Excel File at https://goo.gl/wRxNOe

Thnx
Satdeep

Comment: Was VBA selected by choice or force? Please upload any code that you have tried so far.

Comment: By choice. I am still getting to know VBA as I mentioned earlier. All i have managed till now is to enter all the keywords in an array. My thought process is to use the array contents as filter one by one in the URL sheet.

Comment: [Can you improvise this?](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/549322-using-visual-basic-applications-find-if-any-keyword-exists-string.html)

Comment: This is a little difficult for me to understand. :-( But from what I understand the logic used in the above link is the other way round.

Comment: Simple solution: add a formula column to the data to be filtered which returns True/False depending on whether there is a match to any keyword; for pure VBA, you'll need to create an array of the matching values and then filter using that.

Comment: Hey Rory, for the formula part, won't it search for the exact value instead of a part of the value? Can you help me with the VBA code since Im very new to this

Comment: Not if you use the right formula, no... :)

Answer (score 0):

Filters are not needed for this task:

```
Sub GatherData()
'  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641317/using-multiple-filters-in-vba-excel-2010
   Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, v1 As String, v2 As String
   Dim N1 As Long, N2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long, K As Long
   Set s1 = Sheets("URLs")
   Set s2 = Sheets("keywords")

   N1 = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   N2 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   K = 1

   For j = 1 To N2
      v2 = s2.Cells(j, 1).Value
      For i = 2 To N1
         v1 = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
         If InStr(v1, v2) > 0 Then
            s1.Cells(i, 1).Copy s2.Cells(K, 2)
            K = K + 1
         End If
      Next i
   Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: It works, but I do not want to return those values in another sheet. What I want is the filtered result to come up so that I can delete them

Comment: @satdeepsingh Then let us wait for another answer.

Comment: The macro you provided above is case sensitive while comparing. Any ideas why?

Comment: @satdeepsingh  that is the way *InStr()* works.............very easy to make it insensitive.............is that what you want??

Comment: Was able to make the above code work irrespective of the case. Changed `If InStr(v1, v2) > 0 Then` to `If InStr(Application.Proper(v1), Application.Proper(v2)) > 0 Then`

Comment: @satdeepsingh  Good job!!

Comment: But I would still appreciate if I can get a macro that does not return those values in another sheet. What I want is the filtered result to come up so that I can delete them

Comment: @satdeepsingh  Not sure how to let the macro allow you to take action??

Comment: I have an idea that might work. Why not apply a vlookup on the main sheet from the result sheet and then delete every row containing #value or #NA. Can this be done via VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find a work around. Added two macros and called them within the first one that Gary's Student provided above.

Below are the two macros used:

```
Worksheets("URLs").Activate
Range("B2").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Result!C1,1,0)"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B2716")
Range("B2:B2716").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$2716").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    "=#VALUE!", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=#N/A"
Range("A1:B2716").Select
Range("B1").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Approved List").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("B:B").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

---

```
Sheets("URLs").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A3").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Sheets("Approved List").Select
```

Thanks everyone for helping me out here